# AppDelegateから現在アクティブなUIViewControllerを取得したい

Tags: swift, xcode

Notificationを利用するのに、現在アクティブなUIViewControllerを知りたいのです

Objective-Cの場合には
[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
で調べられるかいてあったのですが、
swiftではどのようにして調べられるのでしょうか？
StorybordIDでもtitleでもどちらでもいいです

Answer (score 1):

質問にあるコードを単純にSwiftに変換すると、こんな感じになります。
（AppDelegate内部のメソッドから使用します）

```
if let vc = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
    // vcにUIViewControllerが入っている
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。取得できました。